# What is the best method to download multiple image in async mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

What is the best method to download multiple images in async mode for an iPhone project?

Comment: `LazyTableImages` does the same thing you are asking for... see my detailed answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) project.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides sample source code, which performs similar functionality -- [Here is the sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Don't get confused with the `ParseOperation` Class. It is just the separate implementation of the XML Parsing functionality.

Additionally -- Apple has updated this code to use `Blocks (GCD)`. Hope that will help you...